# Roads overwrite railways in deep tunnels

Tags: mapnik, cartocss

I'm trying to set up a tileserver to deliver a custom map of London's railway system using CartoCSS and Mapnik. London has overground lines, underground lines, a light railway and a tram system.

I have split the railways into a separate layer from the roads and this railway layer is the last layer in project.mml. If I comment out the road layers, the railways are drawn correctly. If I comment out the railways, the roads are drawn correctly.

However, when I draw both the road and railway layers, the bits that run in tunnels are displayed correctly only where they run underneath parks and water; where the tunnels are under roads, the roads obscure the railways in the tunnels.

While there are aspect of attachments, the layernotnull field and z_order that I don't fully understand and might not have fully experimented with yet, my understanding is that each layer in the project file is drawn, top to bottom in the file (bottom to top on the map canvas) and so I don't understand how the roads always come out on top.

Am I missing something obvious?

Edit:

[image: Rail under road]

Here, the purple line is an underground railway, being drawn in the last layer in the project.mml file. It appear correctly on top of buildings and parks but roads are drawn on top of it - it is this bit I don't understand.

Comment: do you have a sample? does "A map style for railway infrastructure" help? https://github.com/OpenRailwayMap/OpenRailwayMap-CartoCSS/blob/master/standard.mml

Comment: That will be of enormous help to me in the future, so thanks for that! But it doesn't have roads drawn on it so doesn't answer the current question. I have added a picture to show the problem.

Comment: I think you need to use rules (hard to tell without viewing your .mml code) https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:Moresby/Understanding_Mapnik/Using_filters_to_represent_data